# C++ nested switches duplicate value error

Tags: c++, switch-statement, valueerror

so this is the code that im trying to get to work but it displays "duplicate case value" whenever it reaches for B
im a first year college student so i might have used a wrong format or i might be overlooking something i really dont seem to figure out the problem so i turn to you guys for help

```
char dep;
 int exp;
 
 cout<<"please enter your department, A, B OR C: ";
 cin>>dep;
 
 cout<<"please enter your years of experience ";
 cin>>exp;
 
switch(dep)
 {
    
        case 'A' || 'a' :{
                             switch (exp) {
                                case 5:
                                    cout<<"you will recieve a 5% raise and 2.5% extra due to your experience";
                                break;
                                defualt : cout<<"you get 5% raise";
                                break;
                               }
            
          }     
        break;
        
        case 'B' || 'b' :{
                            switch (exp) {
                                case 5:
                                cout<<"you will recieve a 2% raise and 2.5% extra due to your experience";
                                break;
                                defualt : cout<<"you get 2% raise";
                                break;
                               }
          }
        break;
```

Comment: `case 'A' || 'a' ` is wrong. Use 2 cases instead  case 'A`:  case 'a':

Comment: `case 'A' || 'a'` - not how the language works. You need two cases. one can be a fall through to the other. E.g `case 'A'; case 'a':` As written you have two tests for `true`. And fyi, the nesting has nothing to do with this.

Comment: The both `'A' || 'a'` and `'B' || 'b' ` are true (non zero values are converted to true implicitly), so you get two `case true:`, and the compiler outputs the error.

Comment: For something as simple as this I would rather recommend `dep = std::tolower(dep); if (dep == 'a') { /* Code for A */ } else if (dep == 'b') { /* Code for B */ } else { /* Neither */ }`

Comment: Either way, even with a `switch` you need a `default` case (the last `else` in my recommendation), to handle the case when the user doesn't give the expected input (and follow the [robustness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No you don't.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Care to elaborate? No I shouldn't recommend `if else`? Or no there should not be a `default` case handling invalid input?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Neither. But you claimed "you _need_ a `default` case" which is simply not true.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Okay it's not absolutely *needed*, but then it would become very hard to handle invalid input. Never trust the user and always expect invalid input. Be liberal in what you expect, but be ready to handle the unexpected.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude They certainly _should_ write one.

Answer (score 0):

Though it compiles (or would without the `B` version), and spells what you wanted if roughly translated to English, `case 'A' || 'a'` does not do what you think it does.

The expression after `case` is treated as an exact match for the selection statement — [it's compared exactly to `dep`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.switch#5.sentence-2). You can't throw in a more complex expression and expect it to be "unrolled" into multiple comparisons. Think of `switch`/`case` as a simple lookup table, rather than an intelligent branching feature (that's what `if` is for!).

Perhaps confusingly, the expression `'A' || 'a'` is valid in its own right, but (like any expression) it evaluates to a single value: either `true` or `false`, depending on whether either of the operands if "truthy". In this particular example, neither has ASCII value zero so both is truthy, and the expression is always `true`. [It'll be converted to the type of `dep`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.switch#2.sentence-4) ([the rules say it becomes `1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom#6)) and used for that exact lookup.

Since you did this with `'B'` and `'b'` too, [you do then indeed have two equivalent `case`s](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.switch#2.sentence-5).

Instead, write a separate case for each condition. Fortunately, since [`case`s fall through](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.switch#6.sentence-1), you don't need to repeat the "body" of the case: you can just put the two `case`s next to each other; just don't put a `break` between them:

```
case 'A':
case 'a':
   // code here
   break;

case 'B':
case 'b':
   // code here
```

By the way, you misspelt `default`.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh i see, i didnt know that this would be a problem, thank you so much

Comment: @Kas-per You bet.